# How to get CheckBox or RadioButton textAppearance?

Tags: android, radio-button, android-checkbox

I have some radio buttons and/or check boxes in my layout and I would like that my `TextViews` that are around have the same text appearance (size, color, etc.).

Basically, I am looking for something like the following:

```
<TextView
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceRadioButton"
    ...
/>
```

Is it possible to achieve this in some other way perhaps?

P.S: I do not want to change the 'default' text appearance that radio buttons and check boxes already have. Also, I am not looking for a run-time solution but the one that utilizes xml layout file.

Answer (score 2):

I found it now, which seems to work at least for `Theme.Holo` and `Theme.Holo.Light`:

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"
android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimaryDisableOnly"
```

Those are the two things that are set on a `CheckBox` that are not set on a `TextView`.

Answer (score -1):

According to the Android API docs (emphasis mine):

> android:textAppearance
>
> Base text color, typeface, size, and style.
>
> **Must be a reference to another resource**, in the form "@[+][package:]type:name" or to a theme attribute in the form "?[package:][type:]name".
>
> This corresponds to the global attribute resource symbol textAppearance.

This suggests that you just need to reference the same resource in the  `android:textAppearance` attributes for your `TextView`s that you use in your `RadioButton`s.

Comment: I use default text appearance in radio button. How can I reference that one?

Comment: Isn't the default appearance the same on your other `TextView`s?

Comment: No, default text appearance of (for example) radio button, differs both in size and color from the default appearance of text view.